# What are the solutions to Ha.ckers.org challenge?

Tags: security, cookies, https, headers

I was looking around to test my HTTP knowledge, and I found the ha.ckers.org challenges [here](http://ha.ckers.org/challenge/) and [here](http://ha.ckers.org/challenge2/)

I spent lot of time trying to figure out how to find the captcha and how to change some cookies but I didn't find a clue!!

that's the first clue for example :

> **Clue 1:**
>   TWVldCB1cyBhdCAoSSdtIGEpIEJsYWNraGF0IGZvciBhIHRlZS1zaGlydC4gIERyb3AgbWUgYW4g

does anyone here has a clue on how to begin or the whole solution if possible?

Comment: Come on. No spoilers. Rule #10 reads: ,,Some parts are hard [...]''. Rule #11 reads: ,,Have fun''.

Comment: well it has more than 2 years now and it's closed also! so where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The clue looks like it has been [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded:

It reads: "Meet us at (I'm a) Blackhat for a tee-shirt.  Drop me an "